Add values for a custom component on a lightning record page
I got a custom LWC component created that can be placed on a record page. Here is the meta file of the custom component.
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>62.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Test Component</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="userId" label="User Id"
                type="String" />
            <property name="workOrderId" label="Work Order Id"
                type="String" />
            <property name="test Name" label="TestName"
                type="String" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

My custom component also requires the above input values to be passed in to pull in the related records. I do see the above values are ready to be populated with values from the record page. But I am wondering how do I add values onto a record page.


What do you mean by "add values onto a record page"?  Do you mean how do you reference those two properties in your custom LWC Javascript code?

@DavidCheng Right, I want to pass in values from the record page to the LWC js code. I know how it is done when adding LWC component inside flows but this one is not inside a flow, it is a directly added to the record page.

You can reference the variables set on the record page by importing the api decorator to your JS file:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

And then declare them here:
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api userId;
    @api workOrderId;
    ...
}


Yes this the way I have done it. But I dont know in what format we should put in the values on the record page
